# Java. Discard cards in poker using an array of indices

Tags: java, poker

I am trying to write code for a poker game to delete cards at certain indices using an array.

The code i have so far is the following and is not working.

ncard is the number of cards currently in the hand. any help would be appreciated.

```
/** 
 * discard the indexed cards from the Hand.
 * @param indices the indices of cards to delete.
 * @return true if all Cards deleted, false if not.
 */

public boolean discard(int[] indices){

    int i = 0;

    while (i < indices.length){

        if (indices[i] < 0 || indices[i] >= ncard)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int in = indices[i]; in < ncard; in++){
            cards[in] = null;
            ncard--;


        }
        i++; 

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: it will discard too many cards at times.

Comment: It looks like you have the cards in a static array, and are setting the discarded indices to null. If you discard n cards and then try to discard a card at index 52-n, the metdod will return false and not discard any more cards. Also, you are not discarding cards at the indices, you are discarding every card between each given index and ```ncard``` (which doesn't represent the index of the last card since the nulls are at arbitrary locations)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the cards in a static array, and are setting the discarded indices to null. If you discard n cards and then try to discard a card at index 52-n, the method will return false and not discard any more cards.

You should probably use some dynamic data structure, such as a stack or a list, to store the cards. If you must use an array, here's how to go about fixing your problem:

You are not discarding cards at the indices, you are discarding every card between each given index and `ncard` (which doesn't represent the index of the last card since the nulls are at arbitrary locations). That for-loop should be replaced with

```
cards[indices[i]] = null
deletedCards++;//You should initialize this before the loop
```

After the loop, you should put this code:

```
Arrays.sort(cards, new Comparator<Card>(){
  public int compare(Card a, Card b){
    return Boolean.compare(a==null,b==null);
  }
});
```

It sorts the nulls to the back of the array, and keeps the order otherwise same. Then you decrement `ncards` by `deletedCards`.

Answer (score 0):

I highly reccomend for-loops in this case, since all this `i++` stuff makes the code hard to understand

```
public boolean discard(int[] indices) {
    // check if all indices consumed are valid
    for(int index : indices) {
        // i just use your validation, don't know, if this is correct though
        if(index < 0 || index >= ncard)
            return false;
    }
    // remove cards
    for(int index : indices) {
        cards[index] = null;
        ncard--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My guess is that the problem comes from the validation, but I would need more information to really solve that problem...
Maybe this would be a better validation sorting out indexOutOfBounds (negative and positive) and the attempt to discard more cards than ncard:

```
if(index < 0 || index > (cards.length -1) || indices.length > ncard)
    return false;
```

EDIT: I assume that cards is an array that has the size of your card deck and all cards that the player does not have are null values?

Comment: I believe this solution solves the issue i was experiencing, thank you!